# Troubles with Meteor HTTP calls

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I am new to Meteor and having trouble trying to make a HTTP GET request.  I was following a tutorial that went over HTTP requests, I pretty much followed it to the T but nothing seems to display when I navigate to the page.  I have added Meteor HTTP, but still the function on my client.js file doesn't seem to be firing. I can see the JSON when I navigate to the NYT with my browser, but nothing on my page.

In my client folder this is my home.html:

```
<template name="home">
<div class="page-header">
<h1>Home</h1>
You are home!
<select class="news">
  <option>sports</option>
  <option>politics</option>
  <option>business</option>
</select>
  <h1>news:<small>{{currentnews}}</small></h1>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is the home.js:

```
Template.layout.currentnews = function(){
var news = Session.get('news');
Meteor.call('getNews',news,function(err, results){
console.log(results.content);
console.log('hello from currentnews function');
Session.set('news', JSON.parse(results.content));
});
return Session.get('news');
};
```

and lastly here is the server.js inside of the server folder:

```
Meteor.methods({
'getNews':function(subject){
return Meteor.http.call('GET', 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?callback=svc_search_v2_articlesearch&q='+subject+'&begin_date=20150402&end_date=20150402&sort=newest&api-key=[apikeyhere]');
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have your template names right? Your example doesnt make much sense to me.

Template.layout.currentnews looks wrong....

Your template is called home?

Try put your code in

```
Template.home.rendered = function(){
        Meteor.call('getNews',news,function(err, results){
        console.log(results.content);
        console.log('hello from currentnews function');
        Session.set('news', JSON.parse(results.content));
        });
  };


Template.home.helpers({
    currentnews: function()
    {
      return Session.get('news');     
    }
});
```

You may have to fix the closures.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped .  I meant to write server.js inside of the server folder.  I edited the question just now to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had the wrong template name.  I'm still new to the way files are organized in Meteor.